# Intent.ACTION_CALL hide a number

Tags: android, android-intent, call

I use this to call a number when button is pressed:

```
 Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);                
 callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:79950695"));                 
 startActivity(callIntent);
```

Is there a way to hide the number ??
What I want to get is a pop with new call but showing only the name without the number ?
Would I need to create some custom Outgoing Call Broadcaster ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to handle In Call UI.
you can save that contact with some name once user clicks on call button and display the name, once done with call you might delete that contact.

You need to handle the settings to display only name but not number in call.

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide. Instead delete the number.

Use this method

```
   private void deleteNumber() {
        try {
            String strNumberOne[] = { "79950695" };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + " = ? ", strNumberOne, "");
            boolean bol = cursor.moveToFirst();
            if (bol) {
                do {
                    int idOfRowToDelete = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls._ID));
                    getContentResolver().delete(Uri.withAppendedPath(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(idOfRowToDelete)), "", null);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.print("Exception ");
        }
    }
```